# Capturing enemies alive in Warcraft tabletop

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

Hey guys I'm playing a human [tinker](http://www.dndwiki.com/wiki/Publication:World_of_Warcraft:_The_Role_Playing_Game/Tinker_Class) in [the World of Warcraft D&D setting](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/World_of_Warcraft_(3.5e_Campaign_Setting)). I was going to have the character specialize in non lethal damage, I was wondering what kind of [technological device](http://www.dndwiki.com/wiki/Publication:World_of_Warcraft:_The_Role_Playing_Game/Creating_Technological_Devices) I could create to capture enemies, since most of the listed offensive features are more about dealing damage.

We are currently level 6, and I would like to stay within the Warcraft content.

Comment: I'm not sure about what, exactly, is yout problem. One of your links have already the guidelines to how you can create new stuff, how to price it, and everything else you need about tech gear. I suppose we can help you here about how to create a specific device (i.e.: "How to define the price and stats for a Net Laucher?"), but this is not the best place to ask for a list of ideas. Could you refine your question?

Comment: I think the problem is that given those rules it's unclear how you'd make something that incapacitates or otherwise imposes a condition.

Comment: I'm closing this as unclear since that link is now broken. If it was homebrew, it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

The damage type dealt is not defined in the Technology Devise Features because you can choose which type of damage you want it to deal. It assumes lethal damage since that is what most players and NPCs want to inflict. However, that damage type could be stated as non-lethal damage in your Definition of Primary Function. For example:

> Stun grenade: Deals d12 non-lethal damage in 10' radius on impact.

The DM would still use the Deals Damage Feature and it's calculation in determining the Technology Score.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to non-lethal damage, which it seems perfectly easy to do on your tech creation system;

It might be a good idea to look into devices that in some way hinder the being it's used on. An Immobile Ranged Weapon device with a high strenght/dex score, plus some additional hardness and hit points is a decent way to model an animated steel link net that's just trying to keep whom it's shot at grappled.

Look for the DM to make a ruling on poison reserves or ability damaging features, as the second any creature has any of it's abilities (Besides Con) hit 0, they are massively incapacitated.

Don't be afraid to source things in from other D&D material. Bolas, Harpoons, and Tanglefoot bags are all your friend here.

While I don't know enough about Warcraft to make this content appropriate, I hope it does give you some ideas on what you should be thinking about.